# Solve a differential equation by finding an integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the following differential equation by finding an appropriate integrating factor:
> $$2x\,dx − (2x^2y+2y)\,dy = 0.$$

I then have to isolate the $C$ (constant) and write my answer. The answer I got was by separating the variables is:

$y^2- \ln(x^2+1) = C$

My answer is apparently incorrect, however I cannot understand what other answer I could have. The other methods to solve an equation we have learned thus far are integrating factor $e^{p(x)}$ and the exact ODEs.  However, in this equation, it is non exact.

Comment: While it is possible to come up with an integrating factor that will give you $y^2-\log(x^2+1)=C$ for your answer, it is more likely you get $e^{-y^2}$ as an integrating factor (since $\frac{\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}}{M}$ is a function of $y$ only) and obtain $(x^2+1)e^{-y^2}=C$ instead.

Comment: To get the other factor directly, you have to "see" that the DE is first-order linear in $x^2$ or $(x^2+1)$ as function of $y^2$. Then the integrating factor for $d(x^2+1)-(x^2+1)d(y^2)=0$ is indeed $e^{-y^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$2x\,dx − (x^2+1)2y\,dy = 0.$$
Since the ODE is separable, the integrating factor is obvious  $=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$

$$\frac{2x}{x^2+1}dx-2ydy=0$$
$$\ln|x^2+1|-y^2=c$$